# install_bitbucket fails with 404 error

Tags: r, bitbucket, install.packages

I'd like to install this Package from bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/mkuhn/parallelrandomforest/

But this is what happends if i run `install_bitbucket`

```
> devtools::install_bitbucket("mkuhn/parallelrandomforest")
Downloading bitbucket repo mkuhn/parallelrandomforest@master
Error in download(dest, src, auth) : client error: (404) Not Found
```

If i run the command from `?install_bitbucket` namely `install_bitbucket("dannavarro/lsr-package")` it works perfectly.

Any ideas

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 LC_NUMERIC=C         LC_TIME=C            LC_COLLATE=C         LC_MONETARY=C        LC_MESSAGES=C       
 [7] LC_PAPER=C           LC_NAME=C            LC_ADDRESS=C         LC_TELEPHONE=C       LC_MEASUREMENT=C     LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] RCurl_1.95-4.5 bitops_1.0-6   devtools_1.7.0 httr_0.6.1     stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the master branch should be called `master`, but they managed to call it `default`.

```
devtools::install_bitbucket("mkuhn/parallelrandomforest@default")
```

Comment: Thanks.
It is not my is not my package.... So the maintainer/owner called it default