# install_bitbucket fails with code 401 error

Tags: r, bitbucket, devtools

I have an R package in a private Bitbucket repository. When I tried to install the package from R (using RStudio) I get the following error (I have replaced my password with `<password>`):

```
> devtools::install_bitbucket("avrmbla/rmbla",password = "<password>")
Downloading bitbucket repo avrmbla/rmbla@master
Error in download(dest, src, auth) : client error: (401) Unauthorized
```

I have verified that the branch is indeed "master", cf. [install_bitbucket fails with 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28064101/2205465).

Do I need to set certain settings at my bitbucket account to get it to work?

Comment: R u behind a firewall or proxy server? Any issues with install.packages or devtools::install_github before?

Comment: I have used both without problems... And as far as I know I'm not behind either a firewall or a proxy server.

Comment: missing auth_user? venturing a guess

Comment: @chinsoon12 could've been, but since it is my own account I don't think I need to use this argument, i.e. username is the same as `username` in `repo` argument...